# How to delete key in object and replace with its value?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a sample json like

```
var obj={
    "results":{
        "grade":"A",
        "marks":12
    },
    "data":{
        "name":"sam",
        "gender":"male",
        "age":10
    }
};
```

Now I want to transform above json to:

```
var obj={
    "results":{
        "grade":"A",
        "marks":12
    },
    "name":"sam",
    "age":10
}
```

I was using for each loop

```
for(var exKey in obj) {
    if(exKey=='data'){
        //replace key data with its value
    }
}
```

But I was unable to figure out the logic which would do this.
So can someone help me here how can I achieve this?
Thanks for all ur response,
But if iam having some complicated json like:

```
var obj={
"results":{
    "grade":"A",
     "res":"fail",
    "marks":12
},
"data":{details:{"name":"sam",
                 "gender":"male",
                  "age":10
                }
 },
 "feespaid":"yes",
 "joindate":"sunday"
```

};

Now if I want to modify or delete some keys inside a key value,some thing like

```
var obj={
"results":{
    "grade":"A",
    "marks":12
},
"data":{details:{"name":"sam",
                  "age":10
                }
 },
 "joindate":"sunday"
 };
```

So how we go inside the json and delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inner` `for-in` loop and use `bracket-notation` to assign `variable` as `key` of `object`

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "grade": "A",
    "marks": 12
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "sam",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 10
  }
};
for (var exKey in obj) {
  if (exKey == 'data') {
    for (var d in obj.data) {
      if (d != 'gender') obj[d] = obj.data[d];
    }
    delete obj.data;
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

**Edit:** Only to delete few `keys` from `Object`, use `delete` keyword

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "grade": "A",
    "res": "fail",
    "marks": 12
  },
  "data": {
    details: {
      "name": "sam",
      "gender": "male",
      "age": 10
    }
  },
  "feespaid": "yes",
  "joindate": "sunday"
};
delete obj.results.res;
delete obj.data.details.gender;
delete obj.feespaid;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It worked.How can I delete that gender key and its value der?

Comment: @HVarma — I have deleted `gender` in provided code using `if (d != 'gender')`

Comment: Thanks..If i want to delete the grade in results key,how can we do?

Comment: .Thanks Rayon.I posted the wrong json.I added a new one in the question..can u please have a look a help me out

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this without using a loop:

```
obj.name = obj.data.name;
obj.age = obj.data.age;
delete obj.data;
```

---

Another way using a for-in loop:

```
for(item in obj.data) obj[item] = obj.data[item]; // Add items from obj.data to obj
delete obj.gender;                                // Remove gender
delete obj.data;                                  // Remove obj.data
```

---

Snippet:

```js
var obj={
  "results":{
  "grade":"A",
  "marks":12
   },
  "data":{
   "name":"sam",
    "gender":"male",
   "age":10
  }
};

for(item in obj.data) obj[item] = obj.data[item];
delete obj.gender;
delete obj.data;

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Spencer..I shared the wrong json der.I posted a new json below in my question.can u help me in that

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var exKey in obj) {
    if(exKey=='data') {
        for (var dataKey in obj[exKey]) {
           obj[dataKey] = obj[exKey][dataKey];
        }
        delete obj[exKey];
    }
}
```

(I need to investigate the solution below a bit more)

<strike>EDIT: Deleting nested properties could be done like this:</strike>

```
var invalidProperties = ['gender', 'feespaid']; //add more if needed
function recursivelyDeleteProperties(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if(invalidProperties.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            delete obj[key];
        } else {
            recursivelyDeleteProperties(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.By mistake I shared the wrong json.I posted a new json below in my question.can u help me in that

Comment: @HVarma look now, see if this fits your problem.